# Alternative animation jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Actually i use this function for move image background in loop :

```
var scrollSpeed = 70;
var current = 0;
var direction = 'h';

function bgscro()
{
current -= 1;
jQuery('#clouds_footer').css("backgroundPosition", (direction == 'h') ? current+"px 0" : "0 " + current+"px");
}
setInterval("bgscro()",scrollSpeed);
```

The problem it´s cpu very high , the question it´s if exists alternative for create this continue move and no use setInterval or writte this by other way , i think this function create the problem actually

Thank´s , Regards

Comment: i would use css3 as most of the browsers support it now... if you give some more information about what your background should do i could look into it.

Comment: what about css3 transitions and fallback ?